# How do i set-up my backend server without over writing data each time it it restarts

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have created my first backend server using node, express, sequelize and nodemon. I have also set-up the tables I want and initialise the data I want inputted into set tables when it runs (to save me time inputting it again). There is also separate data that I have entered manually on the pgamdin browser and other data I have entered via the CRUD functions. At the minute I am unable to enter large volumes of data as my tables keep flagging errors and it looks like they are being overwritten.

I am having trouble getting my server to run stable and I wasn't sure if it is related to the below bit of code in my server.js file. Does the 'force true' mean that the existing table data will be overwritten each time the server is run or do I need to add a "if tables exist" type function? if I was to add say a foreign key would the whole table be overwritten?

I assumed the best practice was to have the code for creating my tables and I have previously created my own tables on phpmyadmin when I used PHP. However as it is my first time creating a backend server and using sequelize ORM and don't want to keep losing the data I have entered.

```
db.sequelize.sync({ force: true})
    .then(() => {
    console.log(`Drop and resync database with { force: true } `)
    initial();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `{force: true}` which is equivalent to  `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`. So whenever you restart your server it drops your existing table along with data. So, if you don't want to lose your data, I suggest you remove `{force: true}`

Answer (score 0):

the `{force: true }` creates a clean state whenever you restart so it is expected to see your data goes away. This sometimes works in development when you are testing out things and you might change your schema as you are developing the application but not ideal for production.

You could disable it from the first place or you can add a checker when you are in production mode to not drop your tables.

here is a good example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  throw new Error("Forced sync is disabled in production");
  // do non force sync in here 
}
```